# Yet another laptop wifi problem, script log included

Tags: networking, wireless, scripts, laptop

Computer was sent to maintenance, wasn't turning on, technicians fixed it by saying it was something like "charge inverter" in the motherboard. They also made a cleaning service in the boards.
The laptop now turns on, sometimes sees WIFI connections around it but fails to connect to any.
I tried updating all packages and rebooting, didn't helped.
Ethernet cable works fine.

Pasted log of the super helpful all in one script: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/x9ssDZq2pn/
I tried looking at the logs but didn't see anything stand out.

Any chance it can be a hardware issue?
It constantly tries to connect but fail.

The logs says "Send auth" 3 times and then "auth with (wifi name)" timed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to AskUbuntu. Your excellent question includes detail and is very helpful. Please keep up the good work.

> Computer was sent to maintenance, wasn't turning on, technicians fixed
> it by saying it was something like "charge inverter" in the
> motherboard.

In your wireless script, we see that the wireless device scans and sees only one or two networks. We also see that the strongest has a signal strength of 20/100. To make and keep a strong connection, I’d expect to see at least 50/100. My current connection is:

```
GBR5   Infra  149   405 Mbit/s  84      ▂▄▆█  WPA2
```

In other words, my signal strength is 84/100.

My suspicion is that, in repairing the motherboard, as the technician reassembled the laptop, that one or both of the antenna connectors were not firmly reconnected.

Please see the gray and black connectors here: https://callnerds.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/wireless-adapter-1024x722.jpg

I recommend that you ask the repair technician to double-check his work.

Comment: Connecting the main to auxiliary can also have that effect.

Comment: It was precisely that! Super thanks for your attention. Will pay it forward.