# Wifi and Bluetooth strength weak all of a sudden

Tags: networking, kubuntu, 22.04, bluetooth

I had my hp laptop fixed the other day….
After I got it fixed I wanted to use my hotspot to browse on my pc, and I noticed the wifi strength on my laptop was so low I virtually had to place the hotspot side by side to my laptop. I also noticed it was the same too with my Bluetooth. Any fix? I don’t know what to do

Comment: How was your laptop fixed?  There is a chance that the cables to the wireless controller may not be plugged in right or might be on the wrong connector.  If you look at https://guide-images.cdn.ifixit.com/igi/eQppXADF2etC6wXO.full you will see the WiFi / Bluetooth card there, and in that image it is missing one of the antennas from the connector.  Both should be connected.  Might need to take it back to where you had it fixed.

Comment: Probable duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338052/yet-another-laptop-wifi-problem-script-log-included/1338066#1338066

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yet another laptop wifi problem, script log included](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338052/yet-another-laptop-wifi-problem-script-log-included)

Comment: Thank you all….I took it back to the engineer, and he fixed…you were right @Terrance.